# ZPL slow to print on some Zebra printers

Tags: c#, zebra-printers, zpl

We generate ZPL-code from PDF:s by first converting the PDF to an image and then encoding the resulting byte-array to a hex-string.
The data is then sent to the printer using the ~DY command via TCP/IP.

The problem is that these labels print fast on all our Zebra printers but not on the ZE500 model, and I cannot figure out why. The time it takes to print seems to be related to the size of the ZPL, which makes sense. But none of our other models are taking even close to as long as the ZE500 to print. An example of our other printers is ZT230.

A label that prints almost instantly (under 500ms) on a ZT230 takes up to 10 seconds to start printing on the ZE500.

I know the size of the ZPL is quite big (between 15-50kb), but it does not make sense to me why it would take longer on the ZE500.

Things I have tried:

- Network troubleshooting, just replacing the ZE500 with a ZT230 using the same network connection, the ZT230 printed the label fast
- Specify different storage (e.g. RAM, flash) used for the graphic
- Fiddling with different ways to send the graphic to the printer (^GF), no luck, still slow
- Tested on two different ZE500 printers to rule out hardware

Here are an example of how the ZPL can look https://pastebin.com/Xn43n7vV

```
^XA^MNM,35~DYE:LABEL,P,P,7963,,<image data>
^PR14^XZ^XA^JMA^FO10,10^IME:LABEL.PNG^FS^XZ
```

Any help appreciated

Comment: Does your e500 ever print anything faster or is it maybe just the way that model works

Comment: What is generating the PDF? Have you reviewed: https://www.zebra.com/us/en/support-downloads/knowledge-articles/slow-printing-throughput-hesitation-between-printing-labels.html